# Merging raster in R

Tags: raster, r, merge

I am trying to merge seven tiles of raster in R version 4.0.3 but it shows error as:

```
Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different origin.
```

The origin of raster are:

```
> origin(f1)
[1] 1.549293 0.000000
> origin(f2)
[1] 1.666904 2.306145
> origin(f3)
[1]  0.02155916 -0.67734774
> origin(f4)
[1] 2.921843 4.800345
> origin(f5)
[1] -2.036317 -1.870532
> origin(f6)
[1] 3.293903 4.393251
> origin(f7)
[1] -0.3293477 -0.2457405
```

and I tried `tolerance=0.1` but its still showing the same error.
The R code is here:

```
library(raster)
merge_forest <- raster::merge(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,tolerance=0.1)
```

These are the raster tiles of landcover(https://www.arcgis.com/apps/instant/media/index.html?appid=fc92d38533d440078f17678ebc20e8e2&fbclid=IwAR3Y3SN7iyaPrzViPzagVH086dZTygvmwoIdZrudbb4EJlJyZOf6zdA13g4).

I downloaded seven tiles that covers the area of Norway and wanted to merge it together and clip it to the extent of Norway.

Comment: You should show us the function call that created the error (I guess `merge(f1,f2,f3,...)`?) and complete code (including `library(raster)` so we know what `merge` you are using) and more information about your data than just the `origin` (`summary` is usually a good idea). You can only merge if data has the same origin and resolution. Yours don't.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: Wrong function, you want `do.call(mosaic, list(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7))`

Comment: Tried but got the same error.                                                                                                     merge_forest <-do.call(mosaic,list(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7))                                                    Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE, : different origin.

Answer (score 9):

The terra package has a new object class `SpatRasterCollection` for image collections than can be used with `terra::mosaic` or `terra::merge`. This greatly simplifies mosaic operations. Here is an example where we: 1) create a vector of raster files; 2) use `lapply` to create raster objects wrapped in `terra::src` to create a SpatRasterCollection; 3) pass the image collection to the `terra::mosaic` function.

```
library(terra)
img <- list.files(getwd(), "tif$", full.names=TRUE) # the $ exludes aux-files
  ic <- sprc(lapply(img, rast))
    r <- mosaic(ic)
```

Comment: I believe the "sarimg" should be img in order to work. I'm editing, but feel free to change back if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Lets consider only tile 32V and 32W.

I tried to create a R script to mosaic those tiles, but it takes too long to compile because of the resample process (10m resolution for Norway extent)...

So I used GDAL:

```
gdalbuildvrt mosaic.vrt 32V_20200101-20210101.tif 32W_20200101-20210101.tif
```

Where `mosaic.vrt` is the output and `32V_20200101-20210101.tif 32W_20200101-20210101.tif` are the inputs (you can include all 7 tiles).

```
gdal_translate mosaic.vrt MOSAIC.tif
```

Where `mosaic.vrt` is the input (previously created) and `MOSAIC.tif` is the output in tif format.

I opened the MOSAIC in R:

```
library(raster)

Mosaic <- "MOSAIC.tif"
RasterM <- raster(Mosaic)
plot(RasterM)
```

[image]

Check if this is what you are looking for. I can share my R script but I don't know the final result because it takes a lot of time to compile.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will have a look at this.

Comment: Great, fast, clean and working perfectly thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You stand a better chance of getting the right solution or help by providing the code you used and some details of your raster data. Without it is difficult to be of help.

Without knowing the purpose of the merge, the solution below might be of help

```
merged_f <- merge(f1 ... f7, fun = ) #insert the function you want to use e.g sum, mean etc
```

If the purpose is to create a mosaic (considering the extent of the rasters) then below by SpatialProgramming (see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740097/merge-rasters-of-different-extents-sum-overlapping-cell-values-in-r), might help

```
merged_f <- mosaic(f1 ... f7, fun = )
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the question.

Comment: You should use mosaic instead of merge as noted in the solutions I gave and pointed out by Jeffrey Evans. You can read the raster package manual for more details on the differences between mosaic and merge functions. see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.4-13/topics/mosaic

Comment: I did it and the error is still the same.                                                          merge_forest <-do.call(mosaic,list(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7))
Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different origin.                                                                                                                          In the RDocumentation link you have provided, it says all objects must have the same origin.

Comment: if you google the error message you should find some solutions that you can try. I don't have your data or anything similar hence difficult to offer any advice. I googled the error and found some plausible solutions even on this platform. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224781/merge-rasters-with-different-origins-in-r

Comment: you can try the solution in this link as well https://asktowolrd.com/geographic-information-systems/merge-rasters-with-different-origins-in-r/

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will have a look at the given link.